# Why are the QGraphicsItem's children not getting mouse clicks anymore if the item is selected?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I am using the `SizeGripItem` from [here](https://github.com/cesarbs/sizegripitem) (with a minimal modification to add a signal) on a subclass of `QGraphicsRectItem` defined as such:

#### Header

```
//! RectItem that sends a boxChanged signal whenever it is moved or resized via the handles.
class QSignalingBoxItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    void setSelected_(bool selected);

protected:
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value);

public:
    QSignalingBoxItem(QRectF rect, QGraphicsItem * parent = nullptr);
    ~QSignalingBoxItem();

signals:
    void boxChanged(QRectF newBox);
};
```

#### .cpp

```
namespace
{
    class BoxResizer : public SizeGripItem::Resizer
    {
    public:
        virtual void operator()(QGraphicsItem* item, const QRectF& rect)
        {
            QSignalingBoxItem* rectItem =
                dynamic_cast<QSignalingBoxItem*>(item);

            if (rectItem)
            {
                rectItem->setRect(rect);
            }
        }
    };
}

QSignalingBoxItem::QSignalingBoxItem(QRectF rect, QGraphicsItem * parent) : QGraphicsRectItem(parent)
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | 
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | 
             QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
}

QVariant QSignalingBoxItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value)
{
    switch (change)
    {
    case QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedHasChanged:
        setSelected_(value.toBool());
        break;
    case QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged:
        emit boxChanged(rect());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return value;
}

void QSignalingBoxItem::setSelected_(bool selected)
{
    //TODO: Test that it works as expected
    if (selected)
    {
        auto sz = new SizeGripItem(new BoxResizer, this);
        connect(sz, &SizeGripItem::resized, [&]() {emit boxChanged(rect()); });
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the child
        // If it's a SizeGripItem, delete it.
        if (childItems().length() > 0)
        {
            foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, childItems())
            {
                auto sz = dynamic_cast<SizeGripItem*>(item);
                if (sz)
                {
                    delete sz;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I apply the `SizeGripItem` in the constructor, the class works as expected. However, I need the handles to be visible and working only if the item is selected. When I run the code above, though, the handles show but any click on the handles moves the whole box (as if i clicked in the middle of the box) instead of resizing it.

Running with a debugger, I see that `itemChange` doesn't even get called.
Why is this the case? And how do I need to modify the class to make this work when the item is selected?

### Edit

This is how the class is then used. I have an extension of a `QGraphicsView` with its private `m_scene` where I override `mouse{Press,Move,Release}Event`s to generate a box via "click & drag".
Setting aside the rest of the class, since the only part of it that touches `QSignalingBoxItem`s are those three functions, I'm adding those. If more is needed, I'll add as necessary.

```
void QSampleEditor::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    QImageView::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
    if (mouseEvent->buttons() == Qt::RightButton && m_currentSample && m_activePixmap && m_activePixmap->isUnderMouse())
    {
        m_dragStart = mapToScene(mouseEvent->pos());
        m_currentBox = new QSignalingBoxItem({ m_dragStart, QSize(0,0) });
        m_scene.addItem(m_currentBox);
        mouseEvent->accept();
    }
}

void QSampleEditor::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    QImageView::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
    if (m_currentBox)
    {
        m_currentBox->setRect(rectFromTwoPoints(m_dragStart, mapToScene(mouseEvent->pos())));
        mouseEvent->accept();
    }
}

void QSampleEditor::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    //TODO: Add checks that the sample is still there.

    QImageView::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
    if (m_currentBox)
    {
        // Add to the StringSample
        auto new_char = new CharacterSample;
        connect(m_currentBox, &QSignalingBoxItem::boxChanged, new_char, &CharacterSample::boxChanged);
        new_char->boxChanged(m_currentBox->rect());
        m_currentSample->addCharacter(new_char);
        m_currentBox = nullptr;
        mouseEvent->accept();
    }
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: A full MCVE here cannot be provided, this is as minimal and complete as it gets. This is a Qt widget application using a GraphicsView + GraphicsScene. This is an extension of a class that gets plugged in in standard Qt classes, in a standard way. The boilerplate code would drown mine own and make an "MCVE" even less readable and usable than this

Comment: I ask for a reason: you point out that itemChange is not called, and should be called, so I think the problem is in your current implementation. :)

Comment: Now, that is different then ;) I'll add a sample of how I create an instance

Comment: Why do you think someone asks for a [mcve] ?, I do not like when they put extensive code that does not make sense, I only ask when it is necessary, and in this case with the method that you try should work but it does not work.

Comment: The problem lies in the definition of MVCE. Technicaly, for it to be complete I'd have to provide a main, ui file, extra classes and stuff that goes beyond the scope of the question. Asking "Can you show how you use the class then?" is different than linking to the MVCE page with the default "give an MVCE plz".  I know the code is not copy-pastable and testable. Sometimes, that simply cannot be provided.

Comment: you can always provide an [mcve], since the code you have is an MCVE + unnecessary things, then your job is to eliminate those unnecessary things and you already have an MCVE, if the problem is the extension there are always ways to share it, you can use github or similar. look at my last answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596332/6622587, with few lines it's practically a [mcve]

Comment: Your minimal example here would consist of a main creating a QGraphicsScene+View, adding your QGraphicsItems, together with the minimal definitions of these items. You're just posting more and more code. The idea is that you provide a self-contained piece of code that reproduces this issue. Chances are that in doing so, you'll figure out the problem all by yourself. StackOverflow is not a cloud debugger.

Comment: @GPhilo Huh? 240 characters is all it takes for an MCVE like that. It's readable in spite of being on one line! `#include <QtWidgets> /*newline*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { QApplication app(argc, argv); QGraphicsScene scene; QGraphicsView view(&scene); scene.addText("Hello, World!")->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable); view.show(); return app.exec(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a given item has any of its movable ancestor items selected, the eldest selected ancestor receives the event instead - even if the item's position overlaps the child items. This is handled in [`QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp.html#7342) - the move event is not handled **if a movable ancestor exists**. The eldest movable selected ancestor receives the event and uses it to move itself, but the descendant items ignore it (here - the handles!).

General notes about the code (yours and the one you're reusing):

1. The type names beginning with `Q` are reserved for Qt. You're not supposed to use such names unless you've put Qt in a namespace.
2. The `SizeGripItem` should be flagged to have no contents - because its `paint` method is a no-op.
3. Pass non-numeric, non-pointer method arguments via const reference *unless* the method needs a copy to modify internally.
4. The `SizeGripItem` needs to have either a `Resizer` or emit a signal, not both - these two options are mutually exclusive.

   In fact, the `Resizer` is a Qt 4 vestige where slots were verbose and it wasn't possible to connect to a lambda. It is completely unnecessary in Qt 5, where a signal can be connected to any functor, including a functor of the `Resizer` type - thus making the `QObject::connect` implicitly backwards-compatible with explicit use of `Resizer` (!).

The following solutions can be proposed:

0. The trivial solution - **this suppresses the primary cause of the problem**: make the managed item non-movable. Handles will then work. It has nothing to do with selection status. It's the movability that induces the problem.
1. Make the `SizeGripItem` movable itself. The `SignalingBoxItem` cannot be movable.
2. Reimplement `SizeGripItem::HandleItem`'s `mouseMoveEvent` to accept the relevant events and react to them. The `SignalingBoxItem` remains movable.
3. Have `SizeGripItem` be an event filter for its `HandleItem`s and process the relevant events as in solution #2. The `SignalingBoxItem` remains movable.
4. Make the `SizeGripItem` be a sibling of the `SignalingBoxItem`. The `SignalingBoxItem` then can be movable, without impending the use of `SizeGripItem`'s handles. Of course no ancestors of `SignalingBoxItem` can be movable then.

The following is a complete example of about 240 lines, implementing solutions 1-3. Every solution has been delineated in a conditional block, and the example compiles with any subset of them enabled. With no solution selected, the original problem remains. The enabled solutions can be selected at runtime.

First, let's start with the [`SizeGripItem`](https://github.com/cesarbs/sizegripitem):

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/graphicsscene-children-51596611
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <array>
#define SOLUTION(s) ((!!(s)) << (s))
#define HAS_SOLUTION(s) (!!(SOLUTIONS & SOLUTION(s)))
#define SOLUTIONS (SOLUTION(1) | SOLUTION(2) | SOLUTION(3))

class SizeGripItem : public QGraphicsObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   enum { kMoveInHandle, kInitialPos, kPressPos };
   struct HandleItem : QGraphicsRectItem {
      HandleItem() : QGraphicsRectItem(-4, -4, 8, 8) {
         setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
         setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
      }
      SizeGripItem *parent() const { return static_cast<SizeGripItem *>(parentItem()); }
      QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) override {
         if (change == ItemPositionHasChanged) parent()->handleMoved(this);
         return value;
      }
#if HAS_SOLUTION(2)
      bool sceneEvent(QEvent *event) override {
         return (data(kMoveInHandle).toBool() && hasSelectedMovableAncestor(this) &&
                 processMove(this, event)) ||
                QGraphicsRectItem::sceneEvent(event);
      }
#endif
   };
#if HAS_SOLUTION(2) || HAS_SOLUTION(3)
   static bool processMove(QGraphicsItem *item, QEvent *ev) {
      auto mev = static_cast<QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *>(ev);
      if (ev->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress &&
          mev->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
         item->setData(kInitialPos, item->pos());
         item->setData(kPressPos, item->mapToParent(mev->pos()));
         return true;
      } else if (ev->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove &&
                 mev->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton) {
         auto delta = item->mapToParent(mev->pos()) - item->data(kPressPos).toPointF();
         item->setPos(item->data(kInitialPos).toPointF() + delta);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   static bool hasSelectedMovableAncestor(const QGraphicsItem *item) {
      auto *p = item->parentItem();
      return p && ((p->isSelected() && (p->flags() & QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable)) ||
                   hasSelectedMovableAncestor(p));
   }
#endif
   std::array<HandleItem, 4> handles_;
   QRectF rect_;
   void updateHandleItemPositions() {
      static auto get = {&QRectF::topLeft, &QRectF::topRight, &QRectF::bottomLeft,
                         &QRectF::bottomRight};
      for (auto &h : handles_) h.setPos((rect_.*get.begin()[index(&h)])());
   }
   int index(HandleItem *handle) const { return handle - &handles_[0]; }
   void handleMoved(HandleItem *handle) {
      static auto set = {&QRectF::setTopLeft, &QRectF::setTopRight,
                         &QRectF::setBottomLeft, &QRectF::setBottomRight};
      auto rect = rect_;
      (rect.*set.begin()[index(handle)])(handle->pos());
      setRect(mapRectToParent(rect.normalized()));
   }

  public:
   SizeGripItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = {}) : QGraphicsObject(parent) {
      for (auto &h : handles_) h.setParentItem(this);
      setFlags(ItemHasNoContents);
   }
   QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) override {
      if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged) resize();
      return value;
   }
   void paint(QPainter *, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *) override {}
   QRectF boundingRect() const override { return rect_; }
   void setRect(const QRectF &rect) {
      rect_ = mapRectFromParent(rect);
      resize();
      updateHandleItemPositions();
   }
   void resize() { emit rectChanged(mapRectToParent(rect_), parentItem()); }
   Q_SIGNAL void rectChanged(const QRectF &, QGraphicsItem *);
#if SOLUTIONS
   void selectSolution(int i) {
#if HAS_SOLUTION(1)
      setFlag(ItemIsMovable, i == 1);
      setFlag(ItemSendsGeometryChanges, i == 1);
      if (i != 1) {
         auto rect = mapRectToParent(rect_);
         setPos({});  // reset position if we're leaving the movable mode
         setRect(rect);
      }
      i--;
#endif
      for (auto &h : handles_) {
         int ii = i;
#if HAS_SOLUTION(2)
         h.setData(kMoveInHandle, ii-- == 1);
#endif
#if HAS_SOLUTION(3)
         if (ii == 1)
            h.installSceneEventFilter(this);
         else
            h.removeSceneEventFilter(this);
#endif
      }
   }
#endif
#if HAS_SOLUTION(3)
   bool sceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem *item, QEvent *ev) override {
      if (hasSelectedMovableAncestor(item)) return processMove(item, ev);
      return false;
   }
#endif
};
```

Then, the `SignalingBoxItem`:

```
class SignalingBoxItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem {
   Q_OBJECT
   SizeGripItem m_sizeGrip{this};
   QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) override {
      if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedHasChanged)
         m_sizeGrip.setVisible(value.toBool());
      else if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged)
         emitRectChanged();
      return value;
   }
   void emitRectChanged() { emit rectChanged(mapRectToScene(rect())); }
   void setRectImpl(const QRectF &rect) {
      QGraphicsRectItem::setRect(rect);
      emitRectChanged();
   }

  public:
   SignalingBoxItem(const QRectF &rect = {}, QGraphicsItem *parent = {})
       : QGraphicsRectItem(rect, parent) {
      setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemIsSelectable | ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
      m_sizeGrip.hide();
      connect(&m_sizeGrip, &SizeGripItem::rectChanged, this,
              &SignalingBoxItem::setRectImpl);
   }
   void setRect(const QRectF &rect) {
      setSelected(false);
      m_sizeGrip.setRect(rect);
      setRectImpl(rect);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void rectChanged(const QRectF &);  // Rectangle in scene coordinates
#if SOLUTIONS
   void selectSolution(int index) {
      setFlag(ItemIsMovable, !HAS_SOLUTION(1) || index != 1);
      m_sizeGrip.selectSolution(index);
   }
#endif
};
```

The `SampleEditor`:

```
class SampleEditor : public QGraphicsView {
   Q_OBJECT
   bool m_activeDrag = false;
   SignalingBoxItem m_box;
   QPointF m_dragStart;

  public:
   SampleEditor(QGraphicsScene *scene) : QGraphicsView(scene) {
      scene->addItem(&m_box);
      connect(&m_box, &SignalingBoxItem::rectChanged, this, &SampleEditor::rectChanged);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void rectChanged(const QRectF &);
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
      QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
      if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
         m_dragStart = m_box.mapFromScene(mapToScene(event->pos()));
         m_activeDrag = true;
         m_box.show();
         m_box.setRect({m_dragStart, m_dragStart});
         event->accept();
      }
   }
   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
      QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
      if (m_activeDrag) {
         m_box.setRect({m_dragStart, m_box.mapFromScene(mapToScene(event->pos()))});
         event->accept();
      }
   }
   void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override {
      QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
      if (m_activeDrag && event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
         event->accept();
         m_activeDrag = false;
      }
   }
   void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override {
      QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
      scene()->setSceneRect(contentsRect());
   }
#if SOLUTIONS
   void selectSolution(int index) { m_box.selectSolution(index); }
#endif
};
```

And, finally, the demo code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QWidget ui;
   QGridLayout layout{&ui};
   QGraphicsScene scene;
   SampleEditor editor(&scene);
   QComboBox sel;
   QLabel status;
   layout.addWidget(&editor, 0, 0, 1, 2);
   layout.addWidget(&sel, 1, 0);
   layout.addWidget(&status, 1, 1);
   sel.addItems({
      "Original (Movable SignalingBoxItem)",
#if HAS_SOLUTION(1)
          "Movable SizeGripItem",
#endif
#if HAS_SOLUTION(2)
          "Reimplemented HandleItem",
#endif
#if HAS_SOLUTION(3)
          "Filtering SizeGripItem",
#endif
   });
   sel.setCurrentIndex(-1);
#if SOLUTIONS
   QObject::connect(&sel, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
                    [&](int index) { editor.selectSolution(index); });
#endif
   QObject::connect(&editor, &SampleEditor::rectChanged, &status,
                    [&](const QRectF &rect) {
                       QString s;
                       QDebug(&s) << rect;
                       status.setText(s);
                    });
   sel.setCurrentIndex((sel.count() > 1) ? 1 : 0);
   ui.setMinimumSize(640, 480);
   ui.show();
   return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Hello, first and foremost: Thank you very much for the extensive answer. I have a few questions. First, about your remark 4), why is that the case? The `Resizer` came from the `SizeGripItem` implementation, while I use the signal to communicate to other objects (that know nothing of resizers, boxes, or views) that the rectangle was edited. Why are the two mutually exclusive?

Comment: As per your solution 1), if I understand the explanation & code correctly, you only make the handles movable and disable the Movable flag from the parent rect. Why is then the whole box moved if I drag it around? Does it have to do with parent-child relationships? If so, where can I find documentation for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: As a final comment, again: my most sincere and heartfelt thanks for providing not one, but three solutions. IMHO, however, compressing everything down to one-liners to fit a full program in 240 lines, while useful to allow testability, does not help those who will come next and read the answer. I had a problem and now 3 solutions, but I feel I didn't fully grasp *why* the problem was there and *how* each solution works around it. I do have some code that I'll dissect and eventually fully understand, but a few words explaining each solution would make this a great answer.

Comment: @GPhilo Solution 1 makes the `SizeGripItem` itself movable - recall that it is a virtual rectangle that covers (in scene coordinates) the managed object. The underlying object it manages cannot be movable in that solution. Solutions 2&3 allow you to have your item remain movable, and they don't make `SizeGripItem` movable.

Comment: @GPhilo There is no compression per se. The code is formatted using Google clang-format, with 3 space indent instead of the default two. If you inspect most any Google codebase, it'll look exatly like that. Locality of reference is important for human comprehension of code - having it physically compact in the source code file is not a bad thing. There are no tricks employed to minimize the code -- I simply removed all unnecessary functionality, and used terser constructs where applicable, since the original code is absurdly verbose.